# Plotly layering with/like ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm looking to create a 3D plot of time series data with a 2D 'floor' pattern.

I have tried to approach this a couple of different ways:

1. Adding ggplot2 and plotly items together - not compatible?
2. ggplotly to add layers into the ggplot vis and convert to plotly - Couldn't figure out how to get the scatter lines to 3D
3. Adding a 2D layer to the plotly vis - couldn't find the plotly version of geom_path()

Currently I have the 3D plot in the following code:

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~pos_x, y = ~pos_y, z = ~pos_z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(width = 4,
                    color = 'yellow')) %>%
  layout(
    scene = list(
      xaxis = axx,
      yaxis = axy,
      zaxis = axz
    )
  )
```

I also have a 'floor' pattern I want in visualized in the 3D plot but don't know how to get it in there, as it is currently a ggplot() vis, which is not compatible with the Plotly vis:

```
floor <- ggplot() +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = min(floorData$x),
      xmax = max(floorData$x),
      ymin = min(floorData$y),
      ymax = max(floorData$y)),
      fill = 'darkgreen') +
  geom_path(
    data = floorData,
    aes(
      x = x,
      y = y),
    color = 'white',
    size = 1.5) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = 0,
      xend = 0,
      y = -6.5,
      yend = 6.5),
    size = 2,
    color = 'darkgrey',
    lineend = 'round') +
  xlim(-17, 17) +
  ylim(-7, 7) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "")) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("")
```

two data files as follows:

**3D DATA**

| time | pos_x | pos_y | pos_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1.061 | 11.736 | 1.468 | 1.001 |
| -1.060 | 11.736 | 1.467 | 1.006 |
| -1.040 | 11.732 | 1.459 | 1.121 |
| -1.020 | 11.728 | 1.451 | 1.233 |
| -1.000 | 11.724 | 1.442 | 1.342 |
| -0.980 | 11.721 | 1.434 | 1.449 |
| -0.960 | 11.717 | 1.425 | 1.553 |
| -0.940 | 11.713 | 1.417 | 1.654 |
| -0.920 | 11.709 | 1.409 | 1.752 |
| -0.900 | 11.706 | 1.401 | 1.847 |
| -0.880 | 11.702 | 1.392 | 1.939 |
| -0.860 | 11.698 | 1.384 | 2.028 |
| -0.840 | 11.694 | 1.376 | 2.114 |
| -0.820 | 11.691 | 1.368 | 2.198 |
| -0.800 | 11.687 | 1.359 | 2.278 |
| -0.780 | 11.683 | 1.351 | 2.355 |
| -0.760 | 11.680 | 1.343 | 2.428 |
| -0.740 | 11.676 | 1.334 | 2.499 |
| -0.720 | 11.672 | 1.326 | 2.566 |
| -0.700 | 11.669 | 1.318 | 2.631 |
| -0.680 | 11.665 | 1.310 | 2.692 |
| -0.660 | 11.662 | 1.301 | 2.749 |
| -0.640 | 11.658 | 1.293 | 2.803 |
| -0.620 | 11.655 | 1.285 | 2.854 |
| -0.600 | 11.651 | 1.276 | 2.902 |
| -0.580 | 11.647 | 1.268 | 2.946 |
| -0.560 | 11.644 | 1.260 | 2.987 |
| -0.540 | 11.641 | 1.251 | 3.024 |
| -0.520 | 11.637 | 1.243 | 3.057 |
| -0.500 | 11.634 | 1.235 | 3.087 |

**FLOOR DATA**

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| -11.89 | 5.490 |
| -11.89 | -5.490 |
| 11.89 | -5.490 |
| 11.89 | 5.490 |
| -11.89 | 5.490 |
| -11.89 | 4.115 |
| 11.89 | 4.115 |
| 11.89 | -4.115 |
| -11.89 | -4.115 |
| -6.40 | -4.115 |
| -6.40 | 4.115 |
| 6.40 | 4.115 |
| 6.40 | -4.115 |
| 6.40 | 0.000 |
| -6.40 | 0.000 |

I am just trying to combine the two into one visualization.

Any help here would be very much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Would love to help you, but don't know what your data looks like. Please consider including a few lines of `data`, e.g. with `dput(head(data, n =))` where n is the minimum number of rows necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Dubukay I've added some data in from the sources. The floor data is constant and that is the entire dataset, where as the 3D data is a sample of 30 from the 300+ rows.